# need to convert this model object from Json format in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

New to dart just need to convert this model object in Json format with fromJson method. How to send
this data by constructor to depict the same thing in dart as by using these model objects coming from firebase. Included full book Model Class into it.
Need Help. Thank you.

import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:get/get.dart';

```
class Book {
  Book({
    required this.author,
    required this.bookID,
    required this.discountPercentage,
    required this.description,
    required this.title,
    required this.itemCount,
    required this.price,
    this.isLiked = false,
    required this.ratings,
    required this.coverImage,
  });
  late String author;
  late String bookID;
  late int discountPercentage;
  late String description;
  late String title;
  late double price;
  late double ratings;
  late bool isLiked;
  var itemCount = 0.obs;
  late String coverImage;
  bool? isRecommended = false;
  Book.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json, this.bookID) {
    author = json['author'];
    bookID = json['bookID'];
    discountPercentage = json['discountPercentage'];
    itemCount = json['itemCount'];
    description = json['description'];
    title = json['title'];
    price = json['price'];
    isLiked = false;
    ratings = json['ratings'];
    coverImage = json['coverImage'];
    isRecommended = json['isRecommended'];
  }
  Book.fromSnapShot(var firestoreSnapshot) {
    author = firestoreSnapshot['author'];
    bookID = firestoreSnapshot['bookID'];
    discountPercentage = firestoreSnapshot['discountPercentage'];
    itemCount = firestoreSnapshot['itemCount'];
    description = firestoreSnapshot['description'];
    title = firestoreSnapshot['title'];
    price = firestoreSnapshot['price'];
    isLiked = false;
    ratings = firestoreSnapshot['ratings'];
    coverImage = firestoreSnapshot['coverImage'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['author'] = author;
    _data['bookID'] = bookID;
    _data['discountPercentage'] = discountPercentage;
    _data['description'] = description;
    _data['title'] = title;
    _data['price'] = price;
    _data['coverImage'] = coverImage;
    _data['itemCount'] = itemCount;
    return _data;
  }

  setItemcount(int count) {
    itemCount.value = count;
  }
}



Future getBooks() async {
    RxInt itemCount = 1.obs;
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("books").get();

    var bookList = [];
    for (var doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
      Book book = Book(
        author: doc['author'],
        title: doc['title'],
        price: doc['price'].toDouble(),
        coverImage: doc['coverImage'],
        bookID: doc.id,
        ratings: doc['ratings'].toDouble(),
        description: doc['description'],
        discountPercentage: doc['discountPercentage'],
        isLiked: false,
        itemCount: itemCount,
      );
      bookList.add(book);
    }
    return bookList;
  }



Book.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json, this.bookID) {
    author = json['author'];
    bookID = json['bookID'];
    discountPercentage = json['discountPercentage'];
    itemCount = json['itemCount'];
    description = json['description'];
    title = json['title'];
    price = json['price'];
    isLiked = false;
    ratings = json['ratings'];
    coverImage = json['coverImage'];
    isRecommended = json['isRecommended'];
  }
```

Comment: Can you include your `Book` constructor, or full model class + json response

Comment: model class included

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/library-tour#dartconvert---decoding-and-encoding-json-utf-8-and-more that helps ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this model class, If you need to update item use `.copyWith` and reassign it

Reading from DocumentSnapshot will be

```dart
factory Book.fromFirestore(
    DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot,
    SnapshotOptions? options,
  ) {
    final map = snapshot.data();
    return Book(
      author: map?['author'] ?? '',
      bookID: map?['bookID'] ?? '',
      discountPercentage: map?['discountPercentage']?.toInt() ?? 0,
      description: map?['description'] ?? '',
      title: map?['title'] ?? '',
      price: double.tryParse(map?['price']) ?? 0.0,
      ratings: double.tryParse(map?['ratings']) ?? 0.0,
      isLiked: map?['isLiked'] ?? false,
      itemCount: int.tryParse(map?['itemCount']) ?? 0,
      coverImage: map?['coverImage'] ?? '',
      isRecommended: map?['isRecommended'],
    );
  }
```

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class Book {
  final String author;
  final String bookID;
  final int discountPercentage;
  final String description;
  final String title;
  final double price;
  final double ratings;
  final bool isLiked;
  final int itemCount;
  final String coverImage;
  bool? isRecommended;
  Book({
    required this.author,
    required this.bookID,
    required this.discountPercentage,
    required this.description,
    required this.title,
    required this.price,
    required this.ratings,
    required this.isLiked,
    required this.coverImage,
    this.itemCount = 0,
    this.isRecommended = false,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    final result = <String, dynamic>{};

    result.addAll({'author': author});
    result.addAll({'bookID': bookID});
    result.addAll({'discountPercentage': discountPercentage});
    result.addAll({'description': description});
    result.addAll({'title': title});
    result.addAll({'price': price});
    result.addAll({'ratings': ratings});
    result.addAll({'isLiked': isLiked});
    result.addAll({'itemCount': itemCount});
    result.addAll({'coverImage': coverImage});
    if (isRecommended != null) {
      result.addAll({'isRecommended': isRecommended});
    }

    return result;
  }

  factory Book.fromFirestore(
    DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot,
    SnapshotOptions? options,
  ) {
    final map = snapshot.data();
    return Book(
      author: map?['author'] ?? '',
      bookID: map?['bookID'] ?? '',
      discountPercentage: map?['discountPercentage']?.toInt() ?? 0,
      description: map?['description'] ?? '',
      title: map?['title'] ?? '',
      price: double.tryParse(map?['price']) ?? 0.0,
      ratings: double.tryParse(map?['ratings']) ?? 0.0,
      isLiked: map?['isLiked'] ?? false,
      itemCount: int.tryParse(map?['itemCount']) ?? 0,
      coverImage: map?['coverImage'] ?? '',
      isRecommended: map?['isRecommended'],
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  Book copyWith({
    String? author,
    String? bookID,
    int? discountPercentage,
    String? description,
    String? title,
    double? price,
    double? ratings,
    bool? isLiked,
    int? itemCount,
    String? coverImage,
    bool? isRecommended,
  }) {
    return Book(
      author: author ?? this.author,
      bookID: bookID ?? this.bookID,
      discountPercentage: discountPercentage ?? this.discountPercentage,
      description: description ?? this.description,
      title: title ?? this.title,
      price: price ?? this.price,
      ratings: ratings ?? this.ratings,
      isLiked: isLiked ?? this.isLiked,
      itemCount: itemCount ?? this.itemCount,
      coverImage: coverImage ?? this.coverImage,
      isRecommended: isRecommended ?? this.isRecommended,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks is there a away to call from Json and pass the doc coming from firebase?

Comment: Reading from firestore needs to get data from snapShot , you can follow [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)